# AWS SDK Boto3 : boto3.exceptions.unknownapiversionerror

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

I am trying to upload content on amazon s3 but I am getting this error:

> boto3.exceptions.unknownapiversionerror: The 's3' resource does not an
>   API Valid API versions are: 2006-03-01

```
import boto3
boto3.resource('s3',**AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID**,**AWS_PRIVATE_KEY*‌​*) 
bucket = s3.Bucket( **NAME OF BUCKET**) 
obj = bucket.Object(**KEY**) 
obj.upload_fileobj(**FILE OBJECT**)
```

Comment: Where is your code that triggered this error?  And what is your boto3 version?

Comment: Hi I have boto3=1.4.4 and botocore=1.5.46
This is code.
`import boto3
`

Comment: `boto3.resource('s3',**AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID**,**AWS_PRIVATE_KEY**)
bucket = s3.Bucket( **NAME OF BUCKET**)
obj = bucket.Object(**KEY**)
obj.upload_fileobj(**FILE OBJECT**)`

Comment: I just edit your question, please check whether it is correct.

Comment: Yes , it is correct. Actually I uploaded in rush so forgot to edit. Thanks and let me try

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by exception raised on "DataNotFound" as in the 
[boto3.Session](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/session.html) source code. Perhaps the developer didn't realize people make the mistake for NOT passing the correct object.

[If you read the boto3 documentation example](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.upload_fileobj), this is the correct way to upload data.

```
import boto3
boto3.resource('s3',**AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID**,**AWS_PRIVATE_KEY*‌​*) 
bucket = s3.Bucket( **NAME OF BUCKET**) 
obj = bucket.Object("prefix/object_key_name") 
# You must pass the file object ! 
with open('filename', 'rb') as fileobject:
    obj.upload_fileobj(fileobject)
```

Comment: I am taking file from Django's form Object.
Like...
`File = forms.filefield()`
So how can I put `with open('filename','rb') ` as my file is already in File object.

Comment: Please check whether forms.filefield() give you a file object or bytes object.  If it return string type,you must convert it to bytes object otherwise upload_fileobj will fail. The documentation explicitly mentioned this `Fileobj (a file-like object) -- A file-like object to upload. At a minimum, it must implement the read method, and must return bytes.`

Comment: Hi I fixed that but still getting same error of UnknownAPIVersionError

Comment: @MayankAcharya : Try simulate a local file object upload and see whether you get the same error or not.

Comment: Hi Thanks, That issue has been sorted out. But I want idea if you can help. I am designing a  django user form that has FileField which takes file as an input and creates fileObject.
I am designing such system, that content I want to upload in aws 's3' storage. I am little bit stuck on that point , I am not able to retrieve that exact file path from the file object and I can't read that fileObject with read mode.

Comment: Please post a new question, tag them as `s3` and `django`. I think a search in stackoverflow may have the answer.